# Выбрать все записи, в которых есть определённое число

Tags: sql, select, mysql

Друзья, вот такой вопрос.

У меня есть два поля в таблице: `id1 && id2`. Нужно выбрать все записи, в которых есть допустим `234`, при том, что `234` может встречаться как и в поле `id1` так и в поле `id2` (!но у одной записи в двух полях сразу не может быть значение `234`). и само число `234` - выбирать не нужно (example: если у одной записи значения `id1 = 234`, а `id2 = 512`, а во второй значения `id1 = 312`, a `id2 = 234` то нам нужно select'ить только `512` и `312`). Как вот такое можно сделать? Кто знает?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT id1 as id
From table1 
Where id2=234
UNION 
SELECT id2 as id
From table1
Where id1=234
```

пробуй

```
SELECT IF(id1=234, id2, id1) as id
From Table1
Where id1=234 or id2=234
```

попробуй так

```
SELECT IF(Table1.id1=234, Table1.id2, Table1.id1) as Table1.id, Table2.username
    From Table1, Table2 
    Where (id1=234 or id2=234)
    and Table2.id= Table1.id
```

пробуй

Comment: Забыл добавить)) UNION - не интересует. Он уж очень много кушает)) Интересует, можно ли каким то другим способом решить задачу.

Comment: написал другой запрос

Comment: @Ale_x, можешь ещё помочь)) Есть ещё одна таблица, допустим table2. Нужно теперь по тем id что мы получили достать из table2, поля username (при чём id что мы вытащили = table2.id). Если можешь помоги плз))

Comment: @ka5itoshka, во-первых, очень не красиво отмечать вопрос как правильный, а потом снимать в связи с тем, что еще что-то хотели узнать. Во-вторых, вчера [вам давали ответ](http://hashcode.ru/questions/151374#151389), но вам он тогда казался не правильным.

Comment: @Deonis, дело в том, что ваш ответ не подошёл. А тут, я согласен, не красиво. За это я очень извиняюсь.